# bash: transform scaffold fasta

Tags: bash, perl, fasta

I have a fasta file with the following sequences:

```
>NZ_OCNF01123018.1
TACAAATACAACAAATACAAGTACACCAAGTACAAATACAAGTATCCCAAGTACAAATACAAGTA
TCCCAAGTACAAATACAAGTATTCCAAGTACAAATACAAAACCTGTTGAGCAACCTAAACCTGTTGAAC
AGCCCAAACCTGTTGAACAGCNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAAACCTTTATCCGCACTTA
CGAGCAAATACACCAATACCGCTTTATCGGCACAGTCTGCCCAAATTGACGGATGCACCATGTTACCCAACAC
ATCAATCAACGTTTGTGGGATCACCTGAAAAAGGGCGCGGTTTGTGGTTGATG

>NZ_OCNF01123018.2
AATTGTCGTGTAAAGCCACACCAAACCCCATTATAGCCCCAAAAACACCAAAAAGGCTGCCTGAACCACATTTCAGACAG
```

And I want to split the all sequences in the file that contain multiple `N` at the site where it occurs and make two sequences out of it.

Expected solution:

```
>NZ_OCNF01123018.1
TACAAATACAACAAATACAAGTACACCAAGTACAAATACAAGTATCCCAAGTACAAATACAAGTA
TCCCAAGTACAAATACAAGTATTCCAAGTACAAATACAAAACCTGTTGAGCAACCTAAACCTGTTGAAC
AGCCCAAACCTGTTGAACAGC
>contig1
AAACCTTTATCCGCACTTA
CGAGCAAATACACCAATACCGCTTTATCGGCACAGTCTGCCCAAATTGACGGATGCACCATGTTACCCAACAC
ATCAATCAACGTTTGTGGGATCACCTGAAAAAGGGCGCGGTTTGTGGTTGATG

>NZ_OCNF01123018.2
AATTGTCGTGTAAAGCCACACCAAACCCCATTATAGCCCCAAAAACACCAAAAAGGCTGCCTGAACCACATTTCAGACAG
```

my (inelegant) approach would be this:

```
perl -pe 's/[N]+/\*/g' $file | perl -pe 's/\*/\n>contig1\n/g'
```

of course that also replaces the `N` of the sequence header and creates headers without a sequence. As a plus, it would be nice to number the new 'contigs' from 1 to x in case there are multiple sequences with `N`.
What do you suggest?

Comment: Why have you chosen to do two substitutions, first `s/N+/*/g` and then `s/\*/\n>contig1\n/g`? Surely `s/N+/\n>contig1\n/g` will have the same effect?

Comment: Can the header itself ever contain multiple N? (Your example doesn't) Btw, you want regex pattern `NN+` (or `N{2,}`); the `N+` matches a single one as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `split` instead of trying to get a regex *just* right, and in a script instead of a brittle and crammed "one"-liner.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = shift @ARGV;
die "Usage: $0 filename\n" if !$file;  # also check submitted $file

my $content = do {  # or:  my $content = Path::Tiny::path($file)->slurp; 
    local $/; 
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!"; 
    <$fh>; 
};

my @f = grep { /\S/ } split /(?<!>)NN+/, $content; 
say shift @f; 

my $cnt;
for (@f) {
    say "\n>contig", (++$cnt), ":\n$_";
}
```

This slurps the file into `$content` since `NN+` can span multiple lines; [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm) module can make that cleaner. The first element of the obtained array needs no `>contig` so it is shifted away.

The [negative lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) `(?<!...)` makes the regex in `split`'s separator pattern match `NN+` only when not preceded by `>`, thus protecting (excluding) header lines that may start with that.  If headers may contain consecutive `N` which are not right after `>` then you need to refine this.

Comment: The comment in the first sentence about "one"-liners isn't criticism of other answer(s). It is my take on suitability of one-liners for production.  Apart from quick little jobs I find them to be good only as easily testable demos of approaches, which should be transferred into scripts. My opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I expaned your perl one-liner a bit:

```
cat file.fasta | \
perl -pe 's/\n//g unless /^>/; s/>/\n>/g;' | \
perl -pe 's/N+(?{$n++})/\n>contig${n}\n/g unless /^>/'
```

the first part is to remove newlines between bases, the second part is to replace continuous 'N'.

Comment: What's the `cat` for? :( Also note that this will remove all newlines.

Comment: @PesaThe for file input, it is easier to do pipeline processing. feed the filename as an argument of the first perl if you like.

Comment: Maybe easier, but creating unnecessary process.

Comment: @PesaThe haha, so you are worrying an extra `cat` process when you are piping two or more Perl interpreters...? IMO you should focus on your problem before any optimize.

Comment: That's not a really good attitude honestly. Let's do this then: `cat file | cat | cat | perl ...`.  Anyway, [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: whatever, I have my own view of the use of `cat`, and I don't plan to change it anytime soon. of course, I could put the filename as the argument of Perl, how hard can it be? but when I begin work on this problem, how could I know I will use Perl as the first part of this pipe chain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163119/discussion-between-georgexsh-and-pesathe).

Comment: @Pesa: I think it is your own attitude that is by far the worst here. Mindlessly committing to the dogma of never using `cat` if it can possibly be avoided isn't a good use of what is really just a rule of thumb. In this case the additional line makes the command much clearer to read, and causes no significant overhead. Note that not one of your comments here has received an up vote, whereas every one of george's has.